How to test implemented methods?
I am new to Go. I am using GoMock to assist with testing. The main question I have is am I supposed to modify the generated go mock file to test my functions?
As I understand, I must pass a mock controller to a new mock of the type I want to test such as this:
mockMale := mock.NewMockMale(ctl)
// insert expectations
user := NewUser(mockMale)
err := user.GetUserInfo(id)

However, I am confused regarding the testing the implementation. In this example, let's look at u.Person.Get(id).
package user

import "github.com/EDDYCJY/mockd/person"

type User struct {
    Person person.Male
}

func NewUser(p person.Male) *User {
    return &User{Person: p}
}

func (u *User) GetUserInfo(id int64) error {
    return u.Person.Get(id)
}

I understand that the reason GetUserInfo(id int64) exists is so that I can call the Get(id).
I get the impression that GetUserInfo must include Person.Get(id) because the mock is expecting that, but then how do I include my custom implementation of Get(id) If Person.Get(id), is always called? Am I supposed to modify the mock method of Getid() that was generated using gomock?
func (u *User) Get(id int64) error {
    if a == 2 {
        func1()
    } else {
        func2()
    }
}

Person.Male:
package person

type Male interface {
    Get(id int64) error
}


Is your person.Male  a struct or an interface ?

@WiselyDCruizer it is an interface, I added an edit for you

"I am new to Go" then it might be best to stop that mocking right here and now. Mocking is a technique that became popular because traditional OOP cannot be "tested" without mocking everything. You can test 98% of all Go code without mocking and need test doubles like fakes or stubs for maybe 20%. Don't start with large mock generation tooling. Don't program like in Java, C#, PHP.

@HCLW What is the error you are getting ? I assume it is "unexpected call to method Get()" or something of that sort right ?

Hello, have a look at https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests/testing-fundamentals/working-without-mocks. As Volker mentions, try to stay away from mocks as much as possible. In Go and in any other language.

Test doubles (which are not restricted to mocks) do have value, though. Stubs come to mind.

The issue with your code is that you need to tell the mock that you have an expected caller called "Get"
 var id float64 = 3
 mockMale := mock.NewMockMale(ctl)
 mockMale.EXPECT().Get(id).Return(nil).Times(1) // here you are expecting your called function to return a nil error, and called one time
 // insert expectations
 user := NewUser(mockMale)
 err := user.GetUserInfo(id)

Without that you would have a failed test
